# Need for different items to appear in React website

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

```
app.js
            <button
              onClick={(price) => test("samosa")}
              class="button-56"
              id="order"
            >
              Order Samosa
            </button>
            <div class="price">Price: ₹15</div>

            <div class="aval">
              Availability:<span id="span">Yes</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="items">
            <img src={im2} alt="" class="image" />
            <button
              onClick={(price) => test("veg puff")}
              class="button-56"
              id="order"
            >
              Order Veg Puff
            </button>
            <div class="price">Price: ₹25</div>

            <div class="aval">
              Availability:<span id="span">Yes</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

cart.js

```
export function test(value) {
  return (
    (document.getElementById("body").innerHTML +=
      `<div class='right'>order ${value}</div>`)
  );
}
```

When i press a button only the one i pressed is appearing but when i press the next button it doesnt work
Example:When i press order samosa it displays on the right but when i press veg puff it doesnt appear just order samosa appears
when i reload and press order veg puff it displays veg puff and when i press samosa after that it doesnt work

Comment: This doesn't look to have anything to do with React.

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example of how to do it in react in codepen:

```
const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState([]);
const test = (value) => {
    setItemsList((oldArray) => [...oldArray, value]);
};
```

https://codepen.io/yardenB/pen/jOKdYbY